# splitting a data frame column -- using the second capital letter as a delimiter

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a list of labels like this.

```
Label = c("ProjectCrash", "ProjectNoCrash", "TreatmentFed", "TreatmentPre", 
"TreatmentStarve")
```

And the labels are in a data frame/tibble

```
myTibble <- tibble(Label = Label)
myTibble
```

I'd like to create two more columns, delimiting on the second capital letter.
So the first column would contain either "Project" or "Treatment".

The second would contain one of Crash, NoCrash, Fed, Pre or Starve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tidyr`'s `extract` by providing regex to extract the data into different columns.

```
tidyr::extract(myTibble, Label, c('First', 'Second'), 
              '([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z].*)', remove= FALSE)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Label           First     Second 
#  <chr>           <chr>     <chr>  
#1 ProjectCrash    Project   Crash  
#2 ProjectNoCrash  Project   NoCrash
#3 TreatmentFed    Treatment Fed    
#4 TreatmentPre    Treatment Pre    
#5 TreatmentStarve Treatment Starve
```

Comment: This works great. So I presume the the regex in this case is splitting into two groups. The first one, indicated by the first set of parentheses, is a captial letter followed by some number of lowercase letters. The second is a capital letter followed by all of the rest of the letters, regardless of case.

Comment: That's right. For your example using regex same as first group would also work `([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `separate` from tidyr

```
tidyr::separate(myTibble, Label,c("a","b"), "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", 
                extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Label           a         b      
  <chr>           <chr>     <chr>  
1 ProjectCrash    Project   Crash  
2 ProjectNoCrash  Project   NoCrash
3 TreatmentFed    Treatment Fed    
4 TreatmentPre    Treatment Pre    
5 TreatmentStarve Treatment Starve
```

In base R, you could do:

```
transform(myTibble, a=strcapture('([A-Z][a-z]+)(\\w+)',Label, 
                  data.frame(a=character(), b=character())))
            Label       a.a     a.b
1    ProjectCrash   Project   Crash
2  ProjectNoCrash   Project NoCrash
3    TreatmentFed Treatment     Fed
4    TreatmentPre Treatment     Pre
5 TreatmentStarve Treatment  Starve
```

Comment: This also works. Thanks! That said, I'm having a little more trouble following what the regex is doing, conceptually. Could I get a hint?